# How to extract specific URLs from a large Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a 621 page document with about 100 URLs I'm trying to compile together. They all begin with "https://open." Can you help me extract these URLs into a single list? I tried to do this manually and it hasn't been much fun. I am still a newbie to visual basic, but I have a better handle on it than any other language. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The task is to find each occurrence of "https://open", extend the found range to the end of the address, write it somewhere, and go to the next. The fastest way of doing this would be to use Word's Find function (on the ribbon's Home tab). Click Find and all occurrences will be highlighted. Click the first one, extend the selection, copy, switch to another document, paste, return to the source document, move to the next highlighted URL and repeat.
If you want VBA, start by googling something like "find all occurrences". You will find code for that. Then look for the "Selection object". You will find code to extend the selection of the found items. Next, learn how to open a new, blank document. Google for "Documents.Add". After that all you have to do is to switch back and forth between your two open documents, copy from one and paste to the other.